# Ошибка функции mmap в коде из статьи

Tags: linux, c

Я захотел вывести картинку через framebuffer в линукс написал код на Си.
Нашел следующую статью:
https://kevinboone.me/linuxfbc.html?i=1
Но у меня возникла проблема с одной строчкой

```
char *fbdata = mmap (0, fb_data_size, 
        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, (off_t)0);
```

Компилятор выдает следующую ошибку

```
invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Функции mmap вроде не возращает значений, но почему автор пишет что она может вернуть какое-то значение?

Comment: *Функции mmap вроде не возращает значений* - это откуда у Вас такие сведения? По ману функция `mmap()` возвращает указатель на void (`void *`). О чем и сообщил Вам компилятор. И на сколько я помню, в старых версиях языка Си вместо указателя `void *` как универсальный использовали указатель  `char *`, поэтому в старой статье написано именно так (допускаю, что не статья старая, а компилятор у автора статьи :-) ).

Comment: Конкретно он выдает следующие:
test.c::38:89: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
   char *fbdata = mmap (0, fb_data_size,  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, (off_t)0);

Comment: Ну так он и пишет, что не может просто так взять и преобразовать возвращаемый указатель на void к указателю на char. Обзовите Ваш указатель как `void *fbdata` или используйте явное приведение типов.. Ну или используйте предложенную компилятором опцию, чтобы вместо ошибки давало просто предупреждение...

Answer (score 1):

Кастуйте `void*` ко `char*`:

```c
char* framebuffer_data = (char*) mmap(0, fb_data_size, 
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, (off_t) 0);
```